# using my home directory in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, home-directory

I started using 17.10 and formatted my drives with 17.10 and allocated 280 GB as home volume. Now I cannot copy anything into it and can only copy into the user file directory which is of the same size?

Running `ls -al /home`:

```
rishav@rishav-Inspiron-1545:~$ ls -al /home
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root    4096 Jan  6 20:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root   root    4096 Jan  7 22:32 ..
drwx------  2 root   root   16384 Jan  6 20:11 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx 22 rishav rishav  4096 Jan  8 13:24 rishav
```

Running `lsblk -f`:

```
rishav@rishav-Inspiron-1545:~$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                      
├─sda1                                                   
├─sda5 ext4         099db229-0008-4861-87e6-e0d75d9a2d8d /boot
├─sda6 ext4         12557f24-9c83-41c4-9a8b-fb55468f7388 /
├─sda7 swap         5ab845a3-18a0-4b36-85c8-289bd9a00c65 [SWAP]
└─sda8 ext4         a47fa7e3-b2ed-4ab1-982b-313fdc628fff /home
sr0
```

Comment: please run `ls -al /home` from your terminal and add to your question!

Comment: ls -al /home
rishav@rishav-Inspiron-1545:~$ ls -al /home
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root    4096 Jan  6 20:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root   root    4096 Jan  7 22:32 ..
drwx------  2 root   root   16384 Jan  6 20:11 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx 22 rishav rishav  4096 Jan  8 13:24 rishav
@GeorgeUdosen

Comment: The user dir you refer to is it `rishav`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen yes.

Comment: That is where you should be working? Are you an Ubuntu newbie?

Comment: Also do `lsblk -f` and paste that

Comment: yeah i am new here...i mean i used 16.04 some time ago and i was able to paste or keep things on my volume itself(not inside the user, like in this case) so i raised the question?
@GeorgeUdosen

Comment: NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                      
├─sda1                                                   
├─sda5 ext4         099db229-0008-4861-87e6-e0d75d9a2d8d /boot
├─sda6 ext4         12557f24-9c83-41c4-9a8b-fb55468f7388 /
├─sda7 swap         5ab845a3-18a0-4b36-85c8-289bd9a00c65 [SWAP]
└─sda8 ext4         a47fa7e3-b2ed-4ab1-982b-313fdc628fff /home
sr0                                                      
@GeorgeUdosen

Comment: please add that out put to your question!

Comment: Where _exactly_ do you want to copy your files and how did you choose the location? Have you altered your home directory (`/home/rishav`) privileges? `drwxrwxrwx` does not look like the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home directory is `/home/rishav`, not `/home`. Put your stuff in `/home/rishav` (you can also use `~` as a shortcut).

Comment: i know this....... my question was earlier in 16.04 i was able to copy and paste stuff in the volume itself which i am not able to do now...I can only copy and paste things in the home directory which is inside the volume. @fkraiem

Comment: @RishavShukla The title of the question is "using my home directory". If that's not what you meant, you should change it.